# GridView doesn't show row on changing datasource

Tags: c#, gridview

[image]

Gridview doesn't show rows with data for inserting and updation both.

Since I have change my gridview datasource after pageload but it doesn't load the
data with this updated datasource and since it's a gridview in c# its not showing databind method().

```
String tmh = m_Project.projdepthrs
    .Where(c => c.DEPARTMENTPHASE == department && c.ProjectID == m_ProjectID)
    .Select(c => c.TMH).First();

LBLAllotedhrs.Text = tmh;
LBLLefthrs.Text = tmh;

String[] splitstring = department.Split('-');
String newdept = splitstring[0].Trim();

var prjdeptphase = m_Project.projectactivities.Where(c => c.DEPARTMENT == newdept && c.PROJECTID == m_ProjectID);

ProjectActivitiesGrid.DataSource = null;
ProjectActivitiesGrid.DataSource = prjdeptphase;
```

My gridview datasource changes on combobox item selection event.

I have tried everything given stackoverflow post but none has worked for me.
Image is show above.

Answer (score 2):

Call ProjectActivitiesGrid.DataBind(); after setting source

Comment: databind method is not coming